# Deploying SQL Server Compact with C# application

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I created setup of c# application, but after installation it show me the error that "Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your application uses SQL Server Compact but you haven't deployed it with your application.

You can just install it on the client machine.

If you're asking how to create a single Setup file that will contain the application and SQL Server Compact than you have two options:

> ```
> Traditional Microsoft Windows Installer (Microsoft setup technology)
>     - Users need administrative credentials to install the application.
>     - SQL Server Compact Edition will be serviced by Microsoft Update.
>     - Can use ClickOnce deployment.
>
> -or-
>
> Private file–based deployment (deploying the SQL Server Compact Edition DLLs as part of the project)
>     - Users do not need administrative credentials to install the application.
>     - SQL Server Compact Edition will not be serviced by Microsoft Update.
>     - Can also use ClickOnce deployment.
> ```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.80%29.aspx